# Collision issue in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Here is a sample of my code:

```
if not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(yolo,blocks):



    screen.blit(moonCollect, [randomListX[i]-stageBackground_x, randomListY[i]])
```

I have two sprites and right now only WHILE they collide, moonCollect disappears. How can I fix the logic so that moonCollect will not appear DURING and AFTER collision?

Appreciate any help, and tell me if I am being unclear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could create a variable to represent if moon has ever collided with your object

```
isMoon = false
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(yolo,blocks):
    isMoon = true

//when rendering
if (isMoon == false):
    screen.blit(moonCollect, [randomListX[i]-stageBackground_x, randomListY[i]])
```

This way, even when your moonCollect is not colliding with a object, but in the past it has, it will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then:

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(yolo,blocks):
```

should fix the problem.

Edit:
(this is probably wrong, the way you phrased it made me think you wanted the opposite to happen)